# Parsing request header for security using web.config

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-config

We have a web service which is denys access to all except a single IP address.  This is configured like so

```
<location path="ASMX/Service.asmx">
 <system.webServer>
   <security>
     <ipSecurity allowUnlisted="false">
       <clear />
       <add ipAddress="[Our IP address]" allowed="true" />
     </ipSecurity>
   </security>
 </system.webServer>
```

We recently installed a Web Application Firewall, so now all traffic now comes from a single source. The firewall however collects the origin IP and puts it into a request header called 'X-Origin-IP'.

Is it possible to use the web.config to read this new header and only allow where certain value exists, or is it better to drop into the code and perform the analysis there?

Comment: Pretty sure you can't do it using the web config, as it is a different header...could probably add some code in your `Globa.asax` to replicate it

Comment: You might use URL Rewrite module to analyze incoming requests, as it allows you to verify HTTP headers and decide what action to take, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference